# Fluent NHibernate - Empty Schema SQL Files

Tags: sql, nhibernate, configuration, fluent-nhibernate, oracle11g

I am still quite confused about NHibernate schema export and creation. What I want to achieve is to export schema drop-create sql file AND/OR recreate database schema depending on the application configuration.

Obviously I started with

```
private void BuildSchema(NHConf.Configuration cfg){
   var schema = new SchemaExport(cfg);
   schema.SetOutputFile(filename);
   schema.Create(true, true);
   schema.Drop(true, true);
}
```

But recently I have figured out, that what actually causes my schema to recreate is  NHConf.Environment.Hbm2ddlAuto set to 'create' and SchemaExport has nothing to it.

Also the files with exported SQL schema exists but they are all empty (0KB), which is my main issue, as I manage schema recreation by Hbm2ddlAuto property.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
The BuildSchema method is called just before cfg.BuildSessionFactory()

I use FluentNHibernate with NH 3.1 and Oracle 11g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your method you execute drop-create and then drop and also enabled writing to database.

this is enough to create the files, make sure you set filename correctly

```
new SchemaExport(config)
    .SetDelimiter(";")
    .SetOutputFile(filename)
    .Create(false, false);
```

to create it in database, this works for me

```
new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true);
```

Comment: and you dont set the hbm2ddlAuto variable?

Comment: IMO hbm2ddlAuto is good for developing but i would never use it in production because when i forget to set it to none it will recreate the schema on every start killing all data. also update is only useful for additions to the schema and since one need more control and explicit versioning/upgrading of schema eases maintenance i never use it.

Comment: sure, but thats exactly what I wanted to achieve (for developement), anyway I still wasnt able to get my schema script generated

Comment: any exception? did you debug and check the value of filename? have you provided an absolute path and looked at the absolut location?

Comment: I've checked several scenarios, no error when I specify a particular file name (the file is created but empty) and I get an access denied exception if I pass path to a directory (f.e. "." or "\\..\\..", but the directory is resolved correctly according to the exception details, and it is a project subdirectory)

Comment: if the file is created but empty, most probably the mappings are not correctly added to the configuration object. make sure the classmappings are public if you `"AddFromAssemblyOf<>()"`

Comment: I am using Fluent Automappings now, although it was the same before I introduced it. Obviously the whole application is working fine, mappings and database access too.

Comment: does new SchemaExport(config).Create(true, false); write anything to the console?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Fluent configuration, check your mapping file for:

```
SchemaAction.None();
```

In my case I commented this line and schema export to file now works!

This post moved me in the right direction: http://lostechies.com/rodpaddock/2010/06/29/using-fluent-nhibernate-with-legacy-databases/

> SchemaAction.None();
>   The next interesting feature is SchemaAction.None(). When developing our applications I have an integration test that is used to build all our default schema. I DONT want these table to be generated in our schema, they are external.  SchemaAction.None() tells NHibernate not to create this entity in the database.

Comment: sorry, but i have no access to this system anymore :) I have switched to a different project, its is hard to say what was wrong, but it is finally done. As far as I am conserned it was more like a typo or a stupid mistake.